# Access the method of another class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Let's say i have two classes in such a way:

```
class Class1(ParentClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Class1, self).__init__()
        c2 = Class2()

    def foo(self):
        pass

class Class2(ParentClass2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Class2, self).__init__()

    def bar(self):
        foo() # from Class1
```

how to access `foo()` from `Class2` if instance of `Class2` is created in `Class1`, while `Class1` itself is initiated in another class?

In other words, the dialog box(`Class2`) must update the list from `Class1`.

**UPDATE**

Initially, I had an instance of `Class0` in `__name__ == '__main__'`. `Class0` creates the instance of `Class1` then I could access the instance of `Class1` through `Class2`, but I need to create an instance of `Class0` on some `main()` function, which disallows me access the `Class1` methods.

Comment: You couldn't do that without an instance of `Class1`. Maybe pass one as an argument to `bar`?

Comment: @rassar, you mean pass an instance of `Class1` to `bar()` as an argument?

Comment: Exactly, or an argument to `__init__`, and have `Class2` store an instance of `Class1`.

Comment: @rassar, you're right! i'm really ashamed of myself. You can  post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper terminology helps... You don't want to access "method of Class1", but "method of an instance of Class1" - which means you need to pass an instance of Class1 to your instance of Class2:

```
class Class1(ParentClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Class1, self).__init__()
        self.c2 = Class2(self)
        self.c2.bar()

    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class Class2(ParentClass2):
    def __init__(self, c1):
        super(Class2, self).__init__()
        self.c1 = c1

    def bar(self):
        self.c1.foo()
```